# Keep html comments in riotjs/typescript from transpiling

Tags: html, typescript, gruntjs, riot.js, readspeaker

i have a riot.js-project, which uses [Readspeaker](https://www.readspeaker.com/) for Accessibility.
on [Readspeaker dev-subdomain](https://wrdev.readspeaker.com/adaptation/adapt-the-reading) is explained how you can influence the text to be read. To have text read out that is not displayed, you need html-comments.

So far so good, but the comments inside riot-Tags will be removed on transpiling the typescript.
In the compilerOptions of tsconfig.json the default value for "removeComments" is false, no difference when set explicite.

To "build" the project we use grunt, in the devtmp-directory, which contains the transpiled js-components, the comments are already removed, before uglifying/minifying.

all configurations I´ve found refers to js-comments, like [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?removeComments=true#code/G4QwTgBA9AVBBmB7REZRBAvNOAjcqUAFLBPgF6HwCuAdgMYAuAlorRCXAI4iOECUEAN44IXagA9CEAL79OY6pIEBuIA).

what can i do, to preserve the html-comments? `<!-- -->`

regards

---

edit, some version information:
As package Manager we use yarn, in the yarn.lock the riot version is:

```
riot@^3.0.4:
  version "3.10.3"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/riot/-/riot-3.10.3.tgz#fe..."
```

How can i determine, which bundler is used? I´ve read that grunt is only a task-runner, but don´t find information for the bundler. 
I don´t have any *.riot files, we have *.tag and *.ts files. In the *.tag files script-node the ts-class is initialized. Or which external ts-files do you mean?

Comment: Which bundler do you use? Which riot version? Are you referring to the script inside the *.riot files or just external TS files?

Comment: Sry, this is my first riot-project, it was previously outsourced. I haven't set up a new one yet. I´ve tried to add some information to the question.